# How to find a classname under a specific parent in jquery

Tags: jquery, classname

I have problem here. Please refer to the html code below:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="second1">
        <div class="third1">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second2">
        <div class="third1">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to know which of the class between second1 and second2 has h1 tag. Because I want to alert with "h1 is here" if it is found under second2 else "h1 is not here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply target on `$('h1')`, then you can use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to grab the parent element, and [`.attr('class')`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to grab the class name(s).

This can be seen in the following:

```js
console.log($('h1').parent().attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="second1">
    <div class="third1">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second2">
    <div class="third1">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Or*, if you specifically want to grab the `<h1>` tag under `.second2`, you can make use of [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as `$('.second2').find('h1')`.

This can be seen in the following (slightly-modified) code:

```js
console.log($('.second2').find('h1').parent().attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="second1">
    <div class="third1-in-second1">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second2">
    <div class="third1-in-second2">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check for the presence of a class with [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), and you'll want to check that the grandparent (`.parent().parent()`) has the class `second2`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
if ($('h1').parent().parent().hasClass('second2')) {
  alert('h1 is here');
}
else {
  alert('h1 is NOT here');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="second1">
    <div class="third1">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second2">
    <div class="third1">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @obsidian, thanks but I want to specify that the h1 is belongs to second2 or if h1 is belongs to second1.

Comment: @JustinDuran -- I've just updated my answer to hopefully showcase this a little more clearly, using `.hasClass()` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let secondClass = $('.main').find('h1').parent().parent().attr('class');
console.log("h1 tag is on" + secondClass);

if(secondClass === "second1"){
    //...
    alert("h1 is in second1");
}else{
    //...
    alert("h1 is in second2");
}
```